# Search Splunk with Rest API without a saved search

Tags: splunk

I am VERY new to using Splunk and have a very basic question. Is it possible to use the REST API to query Splunk without using an already saved search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the search string as a parameter to the [export](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0/RESTAPI/RESTsearch#search.2Fjobs.2Fexport) endpoint and get the results without having a saved search on the server.

```
curl -ku admin:changeme https://localhost:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export -d search="search index%3D_internal | head 3" -d output_mode=csv
```

output_mode is an optional parameter. With xml being the default, you can also specify json, csv or xml.

You can also use one of the [Splunk SDKs](http://dev.splunk.com/view/sdks/SP-CAAADP7) if you want to stick to your choice of language. SDKs make it easier for you to talk to Splunk.

-Neeraj.